# What's wrong with my code for ANOVA test in R?

Tags: r, anova

Could someone help me see why my code in `R` does not produce the correct output or do I have a misunderstanding on ANOVA test?   As you can see, there are three categories for `fertilizer` but the degrees-of-freedom shows only one.  Shouldn't it be two?

I've attached the dataset link [here](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/one-way-anova/#:%7E:text=one%2Dway%20ANOVA-,When%20to%20use%20a%20one%2Dway%20ANOVA,three%20different%20groups%20or%20categories) for those who wish to try it out and a screenshot of my code and its output.

[image]

Comment: You need to specify that ```fertilizer``` is a factor variable.  Use the code ```data.aov <- aiv(yield ~ factor(fertilizer), data = data)```.

Comment: Thanks it works now

Comment: Please accept Ben's response as the answer.

Comment: @JimGrange: I've converted to answer to allow it to be accepted and closed off.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that `fertilizer` is a [factor variable](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Es133/factors.html).  Use the code:

```
data.aov <- aiv(yield ~ factor(fertilizer), data = data)
```

Comment: @AMX: If you're satisfied with this answer, please accept (the tick button) so that we an close this one off.  Thanks, Ben.